# Riemann curvature tensor for geometry surfaces on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, riemann-surfaces

Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface and $p\in M$. The **Riemann curvature tensor** is defined by:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
R_p:&T_pM\times T_pM\times T_pM&\longrightarrow &T_pM\\
&(\vec x_i,\vec x_j,\vec x_k)&\longmapsto &R_p(\vec x_i,\vec x_j)\vec x_k= 
\sum\limits_{l=1}^2 R_{ijk}^l \vec x_l
\end{array}$$
with:
$$R_{ijk}^l =\frac{\partial \Gamma^l_{jk}}{\partial u^i} -\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ik}^l}{\partial u^j}+\sum_{h=1}^n\Big(\Gamma_{jk}^h\Gamma_{ih}^l-\Gamma_{ij}^h\Gamma_{jh}^l\Big)$$
Is this definition equivalent to the first or second fundamental form for $M$? If not, what is the geometric interpretation?

Many thanks!

Comment: That is the curvature operator, the Riemann Tensor is a Tetralinear form which means that is a tensor of type (4,0) which means that you take 4 fields to obtain a smooth function. Roughly speaking The Riemann tensor is related to the gauss curvature, which is the determinant of the second fundamental form divided by the determinant of the first fundamental form, by the sectional curvature which means that for a regular surface it is enough to know the value of the Riemann tensor on two linearly independent vector fields which they define a section of the tangent plane at a certain point p.

Comment: there is only one component: $R_{1212}$